# Number Files to get rebuilt by Make

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to let make determine the number of files to be recompiled before actually compiling? The problem is this: Consider having a quite big project with hundreds of source files. It would very convenient to have a rough idea of how long compilation will take, but to know that, one needs to know the number of files to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is no, because your build could generate files which themselves are inputs to other rules which generate more files. And so on. However if a rough answer is good enough you can try the `--dry-run` flag. From the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html)...

> “No-op”. Causes make to print the recipes that are needed to make the targets up to date, but not actually execute them. Note that some recipes are still executed, even with this flag (see How the MAKE Variable Works). Also any recipes needed to update included makefiles are still executed (see How Makefiles Are Remade).

As you can see, despite its name even the `--dry-run` flag will change the state of your build.

Answer (score 0):

"make -n" will do the dry run. But you can't get the list of files to be rebuilt. May be you can write shell script to store the last modified time of files and get the list of files.

Comment: Yeah, that might be an option, although it might get complicated including dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think a found a decent solution for unix. Here SRC are your source files, HDR your headers and DEP the dependency files (something like DEP:=$(OBJ:.o=.d) )

```
isInDepFile+=$(shell grep -q $(modifiedFile) $(depFile) 1>&2 2> /dev/null && echo $(depFile))

COMPFILES=

checkDepFiles=$(foreach depFile,$(DEP), $(eval filesToCompile+=$(isInDepFile))) $(thinOutDepFiles)

thinOutDepFiles=$(foreach fileToCompile,$(filesToCompile),$(eval DEP=$(filter-out $(fileToCompile),$(DEP))))

countFilesToCompile: $(SRC) $(HDR)
    $(eval modifiedFiles=$?)
    $(foreach modifiedFile,$(modifiedFiles), $(call checkDepFiles))
    $(eval numOfFilesToCompile = $(words $(filesToCompile)))
    $(eval numDepFiles = $(words $(DEP)))
    $(eval NumSRCFiles = $(words $(SRC)))
    @echo $(NumSRCFiles) sources
    @echo $(numDepFiles) files to leave
    @echo $(numOfFilesToCompile) files to compile
    @touch $@
```

This first generates a list of modified files within your source and header files lists. Then for each modified file it checks all dependency files for its filename. If a dependency file contains the current file we are looking at, it is added to the list of filesToCompile. It is also removed from the list of dependency files to avoid duplication.
This can be invoked in the main building rule of your project. The advantage of that over the dry run is that it gives you a simple number to work with.